# How i can remove back face mesh from model?

Tags: mesh

How can I delete the back of a face from an object in Blender 2.77?
Because my object in *XNAlara* posing studio had backface culling and I want it to be fully shown, not partly hidden.

I want the object to look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this if back face culling is enabled:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify? It sounds like you're asking how to remove backfacing polygons from your model.

Comment: It looks like either the normal for that face is flipped (or possibly the face is an n-gon and you need triangles in the other software). Here's some info on checking normals: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html